# Verilog: Difference between `always` and `always @*`

Tags: verilog

Is there a difference between an `always` block, and an `always @*` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`always @*` is one type of `always` block.  It is used for inferring combinational logic.

`always @(posedge clock)` is used to infer sequential logic.

Refer to the IEEE Standard (1800-2009, for example) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

They are different! I used to think they were the same. But it is not.

**always @(*)** means sense anything, compiler would fill it auto. If it is a combination logic, use it! So you won't forget anything and make the function fail.

**always**  means it is sentence would be always executed! If no delay in it, **system halted** and no result would be get when you simulation! Very annoying.

For example, in FSM's next state logic part: if use always instead of always @(*), it doesn't work.

Following is a simple sequence detector I wrote, where these two different. You could write a tb to run it if want.

`timescale 1ns/10ps

module seq_detect3( //detect sequence 10110
    in,     //sequence input 
    clk,    //clock positive edge trigged
    rst,    //reset, active-high synchronous
    match   //out match, "1" for matched
    );

```
input in, clk, rst;
output match;
wire in, clk, rst;
reg match;
reg [5:0] state, next_state;
parameter IDLE = 6'b000001;     //no bit matched
parameter STATE1 = 6'b000010;   //first 1 bit matched
parameter STATE2 = 6'b000100;   //first 2 bits matched
parameter STATE3 = 6'b001000;   //first 3 bits matched
parameter STATE4 = 6'b010000;   //first 4 bits matched
parameter STATE5 = 6'b100000;   //all 5 bits matched

//-----------S.M. & O.F.L.-----------
always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if(rst) begin
        state <= IDLE;
        match <= #1 0;
    end
    else begin
        state <= next_state;
        if(state == STATE5) begin
        match <= #1 1;
        end
        else begin
            match <= #1 0;
        end
    end
end 

//-----------next state logic-----------
always @(*) begin    //Can not replaced by always here!!
    case(state)
        IDLE:   if(in) next_state = STATE1; //0 keep, 1 next
                        else next_state = IDLE; 
        STATE1: if(in) next_state = STATE1; //0 next, 1 keep
                        else next_state = STATE2;
        STATE2: if(in) next_state = STATE3; //0 idle, 1 next
                        else next_state = IDLE;
        STATE3: if(in) next_state = STATE4; //0 s2, 1 next
                        else next_state = STATE2;   
        STATE4: if(in) next_state = STATE1; //0 next, 1 s1
                        else next_state = STATE5;
        STATE5: if(in) next_state = STATE3; //0 idle, 1 s3
                        else next_state = IDLE;
        default: next_state = IDLE;
    endcase
end
```

endmodule